# How can I avoid div from executing new line if one line is already full?

Tags: html, css, divider

How can I avoid `<div>` tags from executing new line if one line is already full.
Let's assume that this div has group of images.

```
------------------------------------
|                                  |
|     Image 1           Image 2    |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|     Image 3           Image 4    |
|                                  |
------------------------------------
```

The images in the `<div>` executes new line during the php loop and appears a scroll bar because of the `overflow: scroll;` code in CSS. My **desired output** is:

```
|----------------------------------|
|                                  |
|     Image 1      Image 2     Imag|
|                                  |
|                                  |
|----------------------------------|
```

Note: Image 3 and 4, prints if you scroll the div to the side.

That's my desired output wherein there will be a horizontal scroll bar and the view of the scroll would be horizontal. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Can you share the _complete_ and _relevant_ code, both HTML and CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `white-space: nowrap;` to your div.

```
div{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Try your-self and you may know that. It's the way that the images are wrapped into one single line.

Answer (score 1):

Added `white-space: nowrap; display:inline-block;` to your div

Comment: elements will never wrap

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```css
.imgbox {
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:auto;
    border:1px solid red;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

img
{
    height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgbox">
    <img src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/storymaker-best-hubble-space-telescope-images-20092-514x268.jpg" alt="image1" />
    <img src="http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" alt="image1" />
    <img src="https://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg" alt="image1" />
    <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-CMIQjovvgcQ/VOy4zOpkW3I/AAAAAAAAAH4/8cE_5moqRFQ/s1600/happy%2Bholi%2Bphotos.jpg" alt="image1" />
</div>
```

> **Note:** If you want only horizontal scroll, you must specify `overflow-y:hidden;` & `overflow-x:auto;` so it would hide vertical scroll-bar and will give horizontal scroll-bar only if required.

Hope this might help you.